# How do I calculate an increase in pan sizes for a cake recipe?

Tags: cake

How do I figure out what to increase in a cake recipe for bigger pan sizes? I have a cake recipe that uses two 8-inch round pans; how would I change the recipe to accommodate one 10-inch and one 14-inch round cake pans?

Comment: How can you have a recipe for **2** pans ?

Comment: @DanielE. It's a recipe that makes enough batter to fill two pans?

Comment: @DanielE... typically for a 2-layer sponge of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the depths of the pans are all the same, then the volume will vary as the square of their linear dimensions:

- 8^2 + 8^2 = 64 + 64 = 128
- 10^2 + 14^2 = 100 + 196 = 296
- Ratio = 296/128 = 2.3125

Near enough, multiply original quantities by 2 1/3

Comment: Numbers above are for square not round pans.

Comment: @DebbieM.  .. its a ratio, it makes no difference to the maths .. no point in multiplying everything by pi.. makes no difference to the answer .. they could be bunny-shaped, so long as they were all the same bunny-shape.

Comment: I shouldn’t think about math before coffee, you are correct the ratio would be the same.